# Reverse dress up doll

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Suppose I have an image of a model wearing some outfit:

[image: doll with clothes]

and another image of the same model in the exact same position and lightning without that outfit:

[image]

Is there an easy and quick way (e.g., requires minimal manual manipulation) to create a new layer on Photoshop that contains *only* the outfit, without the body?

Comment: Select all parts of the outfit (from image with it) using the selection tool then make a layer via copy)

Comment: @WELZ - you know, you should really add that as an answer, obvious as it is. I'd still upvote it!

Comment: @WELZ Hi! I meant some method with minimal manipulation, without having to select the portions manually. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Are you saying you want the lightning to be applied to the outfit? (i.e. the outfit on its own without the highlights and shadows)? Otherwise I agree with @WELZ this is likely the most simple method.

Comment: I don't think that Ps can recognize what is the outfit and whats isn't, especially when it is visually very similar.

Comment: @Ondibobo - it can be difficult to get Photoshop to select stuff automatically, especially if there is a lack of contrast/color as in your example, but you might want to try the Quick Selection tool. If it doesn't work well, manual selection is probably the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do it automatically (especially so with your image where the contrast and colors are very similar) it's very hard for Ps to recognixe which parts are separate (as mentioned in comments above)

Below is probably the easiest method as of writing (June '18) with least amount of manual work.

---

Select all parts of the outfit using the *Quick Selection Tool* (<kbd>W</kbd>) + some manual selection with the Lasso (<kbd>L</kbd>) - from the first image - with the outfit on.

<sub>Rough selection done in a min, spend a bit more time for better accuracy:</sub>

[image: rough selection]

Once all is selected, you can **Right Click → Layer Via Copy**

[image]

Then you can color/apply effects/ turn on or off the new layer to see the character with the outfit and without.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Since it doesn't seem possible to do what I wanted, I will accept this answer if you can edit it to include a disclaimer at the beginning (for the sake of future people reading this) that it's impossible and what you propose is the best method available.

Comment: @Ondibobo I've added that. Sorry it wasn't what you were hoping for